# Install Python's Pandas package on Synology with Marvell CPU box

Tags: linux, python, nas, synology, pip

I have a Synology (DS211j, DSM 5.1-5022 Update 1, Python27) box and I'm trying to install `pandas` package on it via `pip`. Everytime I run `pip install pandas`, I'm getting the following error message in console:

```
ImportError: No module named cygwinccompiler
```

I believe this package should be installed on Windows machines but not in Linux. Is there anything I need to install prior using `pip` utility?